# iPhone - UIView Animation not looping correctly

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, translation

Hey all, got a little problem here and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am trying to animate a UIView up and down repeatedly. When I start it, it goes down correctly and then back up but then immediately shoots to the "final" position of the animation. Code is as follows:

```
UIImageView *guide = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
    guide.frame = CGRectMake(250, 80, 30, 30);

    [self.view addSubview:guide];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    guide.frame = CGRectMake(250, 300, 30, 30);

    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:10];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but in case anyone is looking at this you can just use a fractional repeat count to end on the desired state. If you're animating from A to B and using auto reverse, each repeat will look like this A -> B -> A.  Since you want to end on B on the last animation and not A, just do this to make the last repeat only go halfway (to B):

```
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:10.5];
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

It's a 'feature', not a bug. It's really annoying, but it looks like unless Apple says otherwise, this is how UIView Animations are expected to work.

See this answer: [setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses not behaved as I expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516184/setanimationrepeatautoreverses-not-behaved-as-i-expected/2570064#2570064)

Answer (score 0):

You may set setAnimationDidStopSelector to a custom function and in the custom function you can set up more animations (even ***recursively***). See my answer to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710939/trigerring-other-animation-after-first-ending-animation-objetive-c/2710986#2710986).

Usually I will define an animation structure `(AnimationPath in the example)` to coordinate the whole animation (say, by a counter).